# How to implement woocommerce api in angular 4 to list all the products

Tags: angular, woocommerce

Can someone guide me, How to implement woocommerce api in angular 4 to list all the products

Comment: I have removed the multiple questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the api for list of products in woocommerce [list-all-products](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products)
and this is sample angular app with http client:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/woocommerce
also you can learn angular http client with going through the doc.
[angular http](https://angular.io/guide/http)

hope it help.